# How to display Selected Page in custom menu template?

Tags: html, dotnetnuke, token, ddrmenu

I am creating my own custom menu in DNN using the DDR Menu token template.

In my menu, I would like the menu link of the page that I am currently in to be selected. I am able to achieve this by using the token `[SELECTED]`. However whenever I am in the 2nd tier or 3rd tier pages, the link is not selected. How can I write the code so that the Parent Page Link will be selected even when I am in the Children pages?

This is my code

```html
[>NODE-TOP]
<li class="[?NODE]dropdown[/?][?SELECTED] current active[/?]">
    [?ENABLED]
        <a class="dropdown-toggle forcelink" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="300" href="[=URL]">[=TEXT]<span class="[?NODE]caret[/?]"></a>
    [/?]
    [?NODE]
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            [*>NODE]
        </ul>
    [/?]
</li>
[/>]
[>NODE]
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
    [?ENABLED]
            <a href="[=URL]">[=TEXT]<span class="[?NODE]caret-right[/?]"></a>
    [/?]
    [?NODE]
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            [*>NODE]
        </ul>
    [/?]
</li>
[/>]
```

Here are some tokens that can be used for DDRMenu:

```
NODE - A page
ID - The page ID
TEXT - The page name (i.e. what should normally be displayed in the menu)
TITLE - The full page title
URL - The page URL
ENABLED - Whether the page is enabled
SELECTED - Whether the page is selected
BREADCRUMB - Whether the page is in the current breadcrumb
SEPARATOR - Whether the node is a separator
ICON - The URL of the page icon
LARGEIMAGE - The URL of the large page icon (DNN 6 only)
FIRST - Whether the page is the first in its level
LAST - Whether the page is the last in its level
ONLY - Whether the page is the only one in its level
DEPTH - The depth of the current page in the menu structure (starting at 0)
TARGET - The target window for the url defined for the page (_new or null)
KEYWORDS - The keywords defined for the current page
DESCRIPTION - The description of the current page
TARGET - The target property is used to identify the browser window.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not testing for SELECTED at the lower levels.  That is in the section that begins with [>NODE].

Note that there is also a BREADCRUMB that will be true for all pages in the breadcrumb trail.

Comment: Thank you Joe! Using Breadcrumb to check solved the problem :)